# Uploading large file using MVC Web API Method from Windows phone 8 app not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-phone-8, file-upload

I am trying to upload file from my one of Windows phone 8 application. We are using MVC4 web API which is working perfectly fine until and unless file size is less than 5 MB. Any file with more than 5 MB is giving me 404(Not found) in response.

I think from API side there is no problem as I am able to upload the same file using Fiddler with no error.

I am using HttpClient to post request to service.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Vinod

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the MaxRequestSize in the web.config for the mvc site

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" />
   </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

In IIS 7+ try this

```
 <system.webServer>
   <security>
     <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" /> <!--50MB-->
     </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make these changes in web.config file:

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="1600" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647" />
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
...
```